# google column charts negative value to show highlighted or shaded

Tags: google-visualization

I am working with price value to show in google charts and i need somthing like if the value got negative then column will be highlighted or shaded.
I am using the column chart.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
          // Create the data table.
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
          data.addColumn('string', 'Price');
          data.addColumn('number', 'Rent Received');
          data.addColumn('number', 'Actual Profit');
          data.addColumn('number', 'Total Expenses');

          data.addRows([
            ['Property 1', 250, -80, 589.26],
            ['Property 2', 250, 361.14, 589.26],
            ['Property 3', 100, 260, 500]
          ]);

          // Set chart options
          var options = {
              width: 600,
              height: 400,
              legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 }
          };

          // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
          var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div1'));
          chart.draw(data, options);
      }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is add a [formatter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#formatters). In particular, you want the [ColorFormatter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#colorformatter). This formatter "Colors a cell according to whether the values fall within a specified range."

Having said that, you might want to consider the chart type that your are using. Your legend will have one color for each column. Your requirement is to change the color of each column depending on the value... there is a conflict here.

Comment: yes i can not change the color, so that's why i need to use some highlighted or shaded thing.